# Informix - Default permissions when creating table

Tags: database, informix

So, Im using Informix DB engine to create my  database. I have noticed something peculiar I cannot find information about in the official IBM page.

If you check the definition of my table, there is a line at the end saying :

```
revoke all on "gabriel.barrios".proveedores from "public" as "gabriel.barrios";
```

I did not write that, I simply defined the table attributes. But it seems  as the engine itself is adding that.

Is this the case?

And if it is, how can I cahnge  this default behaviour.

Additionally, could someone clarify ths line's  output :

```
{ TABLE "gabriel.barrios".proveedores row size = 110 number of columns = 4 index size = 9 }

[gabriel.barrios@informix1 ~]$ dbschema -d practico_matias_barrios  -t Proveedores

DBSCHEMA Schema Utility       INFORMIX-SQL Version 11.70.UC8W1

{ TABLE "gabriel.barrios".proveedores row size = 110 number of columns = 4 index size = 9 }

create table "gabriel.barrios".proveedores
  (
    id serial not null ,
    nombre varchar(50) not null constraint "gabriel.barrios".proveedor_nombre_vacio,
    situacion integer not null constraint "gabriel.barrios".proveedor_situacion_vacio,
    ciudad varchar(50) not null constraint "gabriel.barrios".proveedor_ciudad_vacio,
    primary key (id)  constraint "gabriel.barrios".proveedor_clave_primaria
  );

revoke all on "gabriel.barrios".proveedores from "public" as "gabriel.barrios";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Informix default behavior is to grant privileges to the `PUBLIC` role.

As per the documentation ([Table-level privileges](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_11.70.0/com.ibm.ddi.doc/ids_ddi_095.htm)) :

> In an ANSI-compliant database, only the table owner has any
>   privileges. In other databases, the database server, as part of
>   creating a table, automatically grants to **PUBLIC** all table privileges
>   except Alter and References, unless the **NODEFDAC** environment variable
>   has been set to 'yes' to withhold all table privileges from **PUBLIC**.
>   When you allow the database server to automatically grant all table
>   privileges to **PUBLIC**, a newly created table is accessible to any user
>   with the Connect privilege. If this is not what you want (if users
>   exist with the Connect privilege who should not be able to access this
>   table), you must revoke all privileges on the table from **PUBLIC** after
>   you create the table.

What your are seeing is `dbschema` always revoking privileges from `PUBLIC` on the create table output and then adding them back on the privileges output.

```
$ dbschema -d mydatabase -t default_privileges 

DBSCHEMA Schema Utility       INFORMIX-SQL Version 12.10.FC12

{ TABLE "myuser".default_privileges row size = 4 number of columns = 1 index size = 0 }

create table "myuser".default_privileges
  (
    id integer
  );

revoke all on "myuser".default_privileges from "public" as "myuser";
```

Using `dbschema` privileges output and filtering by table `default_privileges` :

```
$ dbschema -d mydatabase -p all | grep default_privileges

grant select on "myuser".default_privileges to "public" as "myuser";
grant update on "myuser".default_privileges to "public" as "myuser";
grant insert on "myuser".default_privileges to "public" as "myuser";
grant delete on "myuser".default_privileges to "public" as "myuser";
grant index on "myuser".default_privileges to "public" as "myuser";
```